# Flutter - How to stop dialogs resizing or shifting when keyboard is activated

Tags: flutter, keyboard, dialog, resize

I have a number of Dialogs that use a keyboard for text input. Whenever the keyboard is activated, the Dialog windows shift position upwards and resize.

I would like to stop this behaviour so that the keyboard is forced over the Dialog content. Is there a way to force this?
I have set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` in my `Scaffold`.

Note that I am using a `DefaultTabController` as a parent widget of my `Scaffold`